# How to capture differences between yaml file entries that differ only for a quote or double quote in Python?

Tags: python, yaml

Consider I have these two YAML files:

```yaml
TYPE:
  fields:
    field1:
      value: 0
    "field2":
      value: 1
```

and

```yaml
TYPE:
  fields:
    field1:
      value: 0
    field2:
      value: 1
```

and I have the following script to compare the two:

```
import yaml

def open_file(path):
    d = {};
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        try:
            d = yaml.safe_load(f);
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc);
            exit(1);
    return d

def compare_dictionaries(type1, type2) -> None:
    print("Comparing...")
    differences = {}
    if type1 == type2:
        print('types are equal')
        return;
    for k, v in type1['TYPE']['fields'].items():
        print(k)
        if k not in type2['TYPE']['fields'].keys():
            temp_compare = {'TYPE': {'fields': {k: ''}}};
        else:
            temp_compare = type2.copy();
        if v != temp_compare['TYPE']['fields'][k]:
            print("diff found for ", k)
            differences[k] = {'new': v, 'old': temp_compare['TYPE']['fields'][k]}
    return differences;

if __name__=="__main__":
    f1 = "./f1.yaml";
    f2 = "./f2.yaml";
    d1 = open_file(f1);
    print("first file opened")
    d2 = open_file(f2);

    print("second file opened")

    diff = compare_dictionaries(d1, d2);
    print(diff)
```

The output of this code is:

```
second file opened
Comparing...
types are equal
None
```

which makes sense. In one case the key `fields2` has double quotes and in the other it does not. When parsing the file and converting to the dictionary results that the key is converted to a string so when comparing the two dictionaries no difference is captured.

Is there a way to capture this difference?

Comment: Use a text-based diff on the original files, not the parsed result?

Comment: @deceze That is not a good suggestion for YAML in general, The layout of the two files could be completely different (indentation, flow/block style), but still **load** to the same data, but give differences for every line using a simple text-based diff.

Comment: @Anthon In general sure, but it’d work for this particular example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with PyYAML, which I infer from your `import yaml` you are using. Not only is
that library outdated (only supporting the YAML 1.1 spec which was superseded in 2009, and that partially),
it also cannot dump your `f1.yaml`, i.e. it cannot round-trip it (load + dump) without losing
the double quotes around `field2` (or adding them to all other scalar strings.

`ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) has many improvements over PyYAML,
including the option to preserve quotes on round-trip. However to make use of the
data easier, the loaded data "behaves" like normal (Python) types, so your test:

```
k not in type2['TYPE']['fields'].keys()
```

will be false, you have to compare the (Python) type of those keys (which will either be `str` or
`ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString`) (apart from that you should leave out the `.keys()`).

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

   
def open_file(path, yaml):
    d = {};
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        try:
            d = yaml.load(f);
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc);
            exit(1);
    return d

def compare_dictionaries(type1, type2) -> None:
    print("Comparing...")
    differences = {}
    type2_key_types = {k: type(k) for k in type2['TYPE']['fields']}
    for k, v in type1['TYPE']['fields'].items():
        if k not in type2_key_types or type(k) != type2_key_types[k]:
            temp_compare = {'TYPE': {'fields': {k: ''}}};
        else:
            temp_compare = type2.copy();
        if v != temp_compare['TYPE']['fields'][k]:
            print("diff found for ", k)
            differences[k] = {'new': dict(v), 'old': temp_compare['TYPE']['fields'][k]}
    return differences
            
if __name__=="__main__":
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    # uncomment the following to inspect that quotes are preserved
    # yaml.dump(yaml.load(Path('f1.yaml')), sys.stdout)
    f1 = "./f1.yaml";
    f2 = "./f2.yaml";
    d1 = open_file(f1, yaml);
    print("first file opened")
    d2 = open_file(f2, yaml);

    print("second file opened")

    diff = compare_dictionaries(d1, d2);
    print(diff)
```

which gives:

```
first file opened
second file opened
Comparing...
diff found for  field2
{'field2': {'new': {'value': 1}, 'old': ''}}
```